# How to remove woocommerce check out page's default email address text

Tags: woocommerce

By default email field is showing email address from wordpress general settings , I want to show a custom text like 'example@example.com' in this field as a place holder value. Please advise

Comment: please search properly before asking a question as there are many links available for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers solved my problem either...
Took me a while to work this out, really simple in the end, just put this at the end of your functions.php file and change the value to whatever you want.

```
function woocommerce_change_checkout_field_value() {
echo "<script>document.getElementById('billing_email').value = 'Your value here';</script>";
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_change_checkout_field_value');
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your dashboard -> Woocommerce -> Settings -> Emails -> Email options, you will see ""From" Name" and ""From" Email Address", change those and it should change it on the email.

More information about configuring some of the basic options on woocommerce you can visit [this](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/configuring-woocommerce-settings/) page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement checkout field customization hook for doing this. Its correct way of doing it.

Please refer to this : https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/

Answer (score -1):

get WooCommerce Checkout Manager 
then complete Replace Placeholder Name of your field.